# Tabulary - missing number - treated as zero

Tags: tabulary

I do understand where the error is about the missing number: `Missing number, treated as zero. \end{tabulary}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{soul} % for strikethrought
\usepackage{xcolor} % for highlighting
\usepackage{booktabs} % for rules within a table
\usepackage{tabulary} % for tables with long lines
\begin{document}
\subsection{Basic HTML Table}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{ C  C  C }
\toprule
\textbf{Firstname} & \textbf{Lastname} & \textbf{Age} \\
\midrule
Jill & Smith & 50 \\
\midrule
Eve & Jackson & 94 \\
\midrule
John & Doe & 80 \\
\midrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

%second table
Table with mulitple cols \hl{in the header}: 
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{ C  C  C }
\toprule
\textbf{Name} & \multicolumn{2}{ C }{\textbf{Telephone}} \\
\midrule
Bill Gates & 55577854 & 55577855 \\
\midrule
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Any idea? And if I drop the first table the whole thing gets even worse cause it reports `Undefined control sequence. \end{tabulary}`

Comment: I'm not sure what's the reason for `tabulary`. Anyway, you need `c` in the argument to `\multicolumn` and not `C`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second table, just change `\multicolumn{2}{ C }{...}` into `\multicolumn{2}{c}{...}`.

Which would give you:

[image]

Comment: Thx for spoting the mistake.